# ffmpeg HLS not append -hls_base_url to m3u8

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

When i use -hls_base_url http://10.10.10.1:5000/hls it's not append in the m3u8 Playlist.

My command i use for generating the HLS Output on Windows cmd with ffmpeg 6.0-essentials_build:

`ffmpeg -y -i  Movie.ts  -c:v copy  -c:a:1 copy  -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb  -f segment  -hls_base_url http:/10.10.10.1:5000/hls/  -segment_time 10  -segment_list  Movie.m3u8 hls\Movie-%03d.ts`

I try with:

`-hls_base_url http://10.10.10.1:5000/hls -hls_base_url 'http://10.10.10.1:5000/hls'   -hls_base_url "http://10.10.10.1:5000/hls"`

Comment: You need to use the [hls](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hls-2) muxer, not the segment muxer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as explained by the ffmpeg tag: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly selecting the [segment](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) muxer (`-f segment`). Its HLS/m3u8 playlist implementation is very limited and does not support the addition of a base URL.

`-hls_base_url` is an option only valid for the [HLS](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hls-2) muxer.

The following should get you close to what you need, given your example:

```
ffmpeg -y -i  broken.ts  -c:v copy  -c:a:1 copy  -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb   -hls_base_url http:/10.10.10.1:5000/hls/  -hls_time 10 -hls_segment_filename hls/Movie-%03d.ts Movie.m3u8
```

EDIT: I see that @gyan put this in a comment while I was typing, so props to him.